# Ionic2/Angular2 syntax error

Tags: compiler-errors, angular, ionic2

I am trying to develop an application in Ionic2/Angular2
    I want to declare a simple models and get compilation errors
    as follows. Please help point the cause of compilation errors.

Model1: global.data.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
@Injectable
export class GDService{
    private _newpost:string;
    private _allpost:string; 

}
```

```
Compilation error:
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

SyntaxError: global.data.js: Unexpected token (5:9) while parsing file:
```

Model2: job.mdl.ts

```
export class Job{
    constructor(
        id:number,
        category:string,
        type:string,
        details:string
    ){

    }
}
```

```
Compilation error:
export class Job{
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

it could be related to your tsconfig file, make sure you have a module defined there, like :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
```

Comment: Tks @Manu, got your point, but I am sure my project is Ionic2 fashioned and below is my ionic info  Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.22
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.12
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.4

Comment: can you share the contents of your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: Hi tks for your response, I have seen your youtube video, nice to see u here (::).  By the way I found my mistake, I forgot to create my project with "ts" option so that ionic compiling didnt recognize my variable declaration syntax eventhough my code is inside ".ts" file.  I created a new project something like "ionic start myapp --v2 --ts" and then my above all syntax were accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this bro.

Instead of this line

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
```

Try giving it like this

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
```

(Kindly check once in ur package.json file whether @angular/core dependency exists.)

Hope this helps you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi Raj, tks for your response, I have seen your youtube video, nice to see u here (::).  By the way I found my mistake, I forgot to create my project with "ts" option so that ionic compiling didnt recognize my variable declaration syntax eventhough my code is inside ".ts" file.  I created a new project something like "ionic start myapp --v2 --ts" and then my above all syntax were accepted.

Comment: Cool.. Glad to hear that.